# Initializing a time series dataframe with a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Python newbie question: I want to create a time-series dataframe from scratch. I have this date_range:

```
date_range = pd.date_range(start='10/29/2021', end=date.today())
```

and this list:

```
l = ['a','b','c']
```

And I want to produce a dataframe that looks like this (basically creating all the possible pairs):

[image]

How is this achievable in pandas?

Comment: Make it easy. Remove the list corner brackets  but assign list to df as column `df= df.assign(x=','.join(l))`, reconvert new column to list and then explode;
`df= df.assign(x=df['x'].str.split(',')).explode('x')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested gen-exp, eg:

```
pd.DataFrame(([d, v] for d in pd.date_range(start='10/29/2021', end='today') for v in ['a', 'b', 'c']), columns=['Date', 'Value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

date_range = pd.date_range(start='10/29/2021', end=date.today())
res = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([date_range, ['a','b','c']]).to_frame(name=["Date", "Value"]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
        Date Value
0 2021-10-29     a
1 2021-10-29     b
2 2021-10-29     c
3 2021-10-30     a
4 2021-10-30     b
5 2021-10-30     c
6 2021-10-31     a
7 2021-10-31     b
8 2021-10-31     c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
>>> from  itertools import product
>>>
>>> pd.DataFrame(product(date_range, ['a','b','c']), columns=['Date', 'Value'])
        Date Value
0 2021-10-29     a
1 2021-10-29     b
2 2021-10-29     c
3 2021-10-30     a
4 2021-10-30     b
5 2021-10-30     c
6 2021-10-31     a
7 2021-10-31     b
8 2021-10-31     c
```